# How to screen capture audio from multiple programs into Quicktime via Soundflower

Tags: audio, video, screen-capture, quicktime, soundflower

I'm trying to set up Soundflower with Quicktime so I can screen record with audio coming from a microphone and multiple programs at the same time.

I'm using a MBP with a Focusrite Saffire Pro 40, I have a mic plugged into the Pro 40 and I need to record sound from iTunes, Plex (via Safari) and a music notation software called MuseScore.

I've installed SF and set up an aggregate device which has the Pro 40 and SF(2ch) ticked, I've also set up a Multi-output device with the Pro40 and SF(2ch) ticked.
I've then set the Mac's audio output to Multi-output device and the input to the Aggregate device.

When I launch Quicktime I set the audio input to Aggregate Device,

When I record, everything gets captured and I can hear the Mic, iTunes and Safari in the headphones but MuseScore, despite being recorded isn't sounding through the headphones so I can't hear it's output in order to be able to talk about it in the video.

In MuseScores I/O settings I can choose from all the available ins and outs but none of them allow me to hear the output that Quicktime is getting.

What am I doing wrong?

Should i be using the 64 channel SF...if so, how can I make it work?

Another option that I have is to take all of the audio into a DAW (Reaper or Logic) and then somehow send the mixed output to Quicktime....but I've no idea how to do that either!